# Loop jquery $.get, how to know when loop is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a loop where I load some content from another page using jquery $.get.

Here is what I am doing:

```
for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
    var myURL = "http://url.com/user.php?user=";

    myURL = myURL + users[i];

    $.get(myURL, function(data){
        $('table').append( data )
    });

}
```

That part all works fine, it updates my table with the data returned.  My problem is that I want to show a loading icon, or even just text that says "loading" until it finishes loading all the data from the other page.

I'll spare you from all the things I have tried that don't work, because I really suck at JS, and it will be embarrassing.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI: that will fire `users.length` ajax requests, pretty much simultaneously. You'd do better to fire a single request that returns back all the data you need.

Comment: Assuming, of course, that the web service supports it or you control it.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL the problem is that users.php actually connects to another webservice which times out when I try to get all the users at once, so that is why I need to get them in smaller chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var doneCounter = 0;
for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
    var myURL = "http://url.com/user.php?user=";

    myURL = myURL + users[i];

    $.get(myURL, function(data){
        $('table').append( data );
        doneCounter++;
        if(doneCounter == users.length)  hideBusy(); 
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks @bdares.  I had to make a few small edits: 1. Should be "users.length" and I had to change the if to doneCounter == user.length, when it was doneCounter + 1 it never fired when users.length was 1.